How to use clinic.js with nestjs
I am exploring a profiling tool for my NestJS code and came across Clinic.js (https://clinicjs.org/). While I see it being used with Node.js, I am unsure how to integrate it with NestJS and understand its benefits. Could you provide suggestions or share experiences if anyone has used Clinic.js with NestJS or any other profiling tools for NestJS?

first things first, install clinic.js with a command
npm install -g clinic        

second, build your folder
npm run build

third, run a clinic
clinic doctor --autocannon [ / ] -- node dist/main.js


or for those that don't want to global install:
npx clinic doctor --autocannon [ / ] -- node dist/main.js
